# Using preg_split() to extract a part of a number on first occurrence of a particular number

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I am trying to extract a part of the string `0044800 999999` at the first occurrence of a non-zero. I am using preg_split() thus:

```
$str = preg_split("/[1-9]/", "0044800 999999", 2);
var_dump($str[1]);
```

The problem is that when this operation completes, it also removes the matching non-zero digit. E.g.
`0044800 999999` results in `4800 999999` instead of `44800 999999`.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: do you want two separate numbers (`4800` and `999999` or as a single string? Are the zero's always at the start of the string?

Comment: The intention is to extract the right part of the split, e.g. `00239023` becomes `239023` @MaartenDev.

Comment: How about [`ltrim($str,"0")`](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj7AI4CLS6W4pEjBVkHJwMDExMLAQMESDJSsubhSkzPyFXJKijJzNUCKdJQMlDStuf7/BwA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could on optional leading zeroes

```
$str = preg_split("/^0*/", "0044800 999999", 2);
var_dump($str[1]);
```

Output

```
string(12) "44800 999999"
```

Or you could split on 1 or more leading zeroes, and check if the returned array has 2 parts in case the string did not contain leading zeroes.

---

You might use a more precise approach removing leading zeroes, and use a capture group to match digits followed by a space and digits.

```
$re = '/^0*(\d+(?:\h+\d+)*)$/';
$str = '0044800 999999';
$result = preg_replace($re, '$1', $str);
var_dump($result);
```

Output

```
string(12) "44800 999999"
```